# Need help customizing jQuery portlets

Tags: jquery, css

I have very little experience with CSS and have no idea how to customize jQuery portlets.

I have the following:
[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9HLt.png)

And I would like to have something like this:
[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKyOQ.png)

Html:

```
<div class="portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
    <div class="portlet-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus portlet-toggle"></span>
            nuevo campo
    </div>
    <div class="portlet-content" style="display: none;">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.portlet {
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    padding: 0.3em;
}

.portlet-header {
    padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    position: relative;
}

.portlet-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 1%;
    margin-top: -8px;
}

.portlet-content {
    padding: 0.4em;
}

.portlet-placeholder {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
    height: 50px;
}
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Seems like more of a CSS question.  I'd remove the AngularJS tag in favor of a CSS one to draw the right audience to your question.

Comment: I just created codepen URL - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aZdwbq...Please check and let me know ..Hope it is helpful for you

Comment: @naga sai a cant open that link because its not complete

Comment: Try opening now codepen URL - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/aZdwbq

Comment: @naga sai a I tried using your css in my solution, but portlets were almost unchanged :(   Image:http://i.imgur.com/w8Riorv.png

Comment: you need to add class - trash in your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the padding from the .portlet class and add more padding to the .portlet-header class.

Comment: Almost there, but still not how exactly how I want it. Image: http://i.imgur.com/24vF91Y.png

Comment: remove the portlet-header margin-bottom

Comment: Good! It worked. One last issue, how can I fix the overlapping borders? Image: http://i.imgur.com/RnNMaJ7.png

Comment: I don't see in the css you have here where it would set the border, but I would try removing the class ui-corner-all from the html of the portlet-header div.

Comment: Nice. That did it. Tyvm

Answer (score 0):

```css
.ui-dialog{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Please add some more information when you answer questions explaining the issue and how you resolved it